# calling function with parameters in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to know how to call a function with parameters in jquery.

Below is the code for jQuery. I am trying to call function callAdapter on button click.

```
$("#button").click(function(){

    alert("message");

    var $usrname = $("#text").val();
    var $ipaddress = $("#text0").val();
    var $port = $("#port").val();

    if($usrname == undefined || $ipaddress==undefined || $port==undefined){

        alert("enter data");

    }

    CallAdapter($usrname,$ipaddress,$port);

}
);



function CallAdapter(userName,Address,Port){

    alert(username);

    var invocationData = {      
        adapter:'TestMobileAppAdapter',
        procedure:'myAdapterProcedure',
        parameters:[userName, Address, Port]
    };



    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess:adapterSuccessCallback,
        onFailure:adapterFailureCallback
    });

}
```

Please assist me on this..

Comment: Can you elaborate what is the problem?

Comment: CallAdapter function is not getting invoked in the button click function..

Comment: First check your adapter, is it working then call it from client side.
Sample codes available at link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html it'll help

Comment: hi.. my adapter is working when i used only javascript to call backend service. but when i am trying with jquery it is problem.. i just want to know how to call function in jquery..

Comment: None of your variables should be `undefined`, they might be empty strings (`''`) though; try testing for that (or simply log to l them to the browser's console in order to be sure the values returned are what you expect).

Comment: If u r testing the code in browser(like firefox) then try using console.log instead of alert. And check if any JS error will found than whole JS will stop working

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into it, hope your problem will get solve

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
     var SubTypeId = $("#ddlType").val();
     var FileId= $("#FileId").val();           
     GetDetails(SubTypeId, FileId);            
});

function GetDetails(SubTypeId, FileId)
{
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '',
        data: {"SubTypeId": SubTypeId, "FileId": FileId},
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // something....
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("Your Message");
        }
    });
}
```

I am using in MVC, I have no idea about iPhone, but in iPad this jquery is working fine